# the filetypes property of FileDialog method has no file extension on windows10

Tags: python, tkinter, filedialog

About python tkinter.filedialog
    I tried to set the file extension type, but no matter what I did,asksaveasfilename does not return the file type ,that is why? It is a bug in tkinter?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
path=asksaveasfilename(filetypes=(('Txt file','.txt'),('Python file','.py')))
print(path)
root.mainloop()
```

the result :

> C:\Users\acer\Desktop\python>pythonfile
>
> It has no extension type

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your path variable. You need to set the defaultextension option like so:

```
path=asksaveasfilename(defaultextension="*.*", filetypes=(('Txt file','.txt'), ('Python file','.py')))
```